# How to rollback create table with sqlalchemy transaction? (sqlite)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import logging
import sqlalchemy

logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("sqlite:///test.db")
connection = engine.connect()
transaction = connection.begin()
try:
    connection.execution_options(autocommit=False).execute("create table test (`id` int NOT NULL);")
    connection.execution_options(autocommit=False).execute("create table test (`id` int NOT NULL);")
    transaction.commit()
except:
    transaction.rollback()
    raise
```

I have this python script. My expectation would be, that database doesn't have table test afterwards, but it does. What am I doing wrong/How can I rollback `create table`?

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.5.3
```

Comment: What version of Python? There seems to be a [related bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue10740) with older versions.

Comment: `$ python3 --version

Python 3.5.3`
so, I would guess, that this version is not affected by the bug, except regression. does the sqlite module have an option to turn on further logging? cause the sqlalchemy logs show me the statements as I would expect them to be.

Comment: At first I looked at status Fixed and date only. But reading the comments, I noticed that, as far as I understand, the patches aren't applied and they are not even sure if it is a bug.
As far as I read, there is also no way to disable this behavior, is this correct?

Comment: From reading the issue it sounds like it was fixed in 3.6.

Comment: Yes, you are right.
with python3.6, a plain sqlite version works, but not an sqlalchemy one